# iterate over file

Tags: python, regex, loops

I would like to iterate over a file and remove a series of lines that match a given regex. I have the script below but it only removes the 1st matching line/regex. How can i iterate through the file to get it to work?

```
import glob
import re

read_files = glob.glob("*.agr")

with open("out.txt", "w") as outfile:
for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "r") as infile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())


with open("out.txt", "r") as file:
    filedata = file.read()
    filedata = re.sub(r'#time\s+residue\s+[0-9]\s+Total', '', filedata)
with open("out.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

Thanks

Comment: are you sure your regex expression is correct? re.sub should replace all instances.

Comment: please elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: db702; the regex is correct.

Comment: satya - i need to eliminate a series of text rows from my file. These text rows are separated by rows of integers that i am interested in keeping.

Comment: The script is able to eliminate all the lines i need to remove except those with double digit numbers. e.g 10. For example, it will eliminate this line:                               
 #time   residue 9      Total.                                                                                         But not this line: #time   residue 10      Total

Comment: I solved the issue, i needed to modify the regex to specify >= 1 digit as follows: #time\s+residue\s+[0-9]+\s+Total. Previously the + sign in the regex was absent.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, i needed to modify the regex to specify >= 1 digit as follows: #time\s+residue\s+[0-9]+\s+Total. Previously the + sign in the regex was absent.